# Testing my php scripts and forms

Tags: php, html, forms, testing

I have two html forms and two php scripts. The first one is a form which is supposed to submit a users email to a .txt file, and the other is a Stripe payment form which uses php code to charge the customer.

Now my problem is that there are some issues with the two php scripts, that I can't figure out how to fix, because I am not really sure how to test the scripts. Normally when testing the html scripts I would just open the html files in my browser, but that doesn't work on my php scripts as the site just shows what is written in the scripts when called/submitted.

So my question is how do I test my scripts, without having to use a hosting account and can I even test it like this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a web server on your local computer to test it out.  I would suggest looking into something called [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com), which allows you to fairly easily create virtual machines on your computer in which you can install anything you like without fear of messing up anything else.  If you go [here](http://www.vagrantbox.es) you can even find a "box" to create a virtual machine that already has apache and php installed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to install a web server locally with php enabled. Since php is a server side language it needs a server to run on, in order to send you back the html, after execution. If you need to see the result on a browser.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29.

Or run your script from terminal (you must have php installed) if you don't need to see the result in the browser and just want to run your script.

`$ php myscript.php`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of PHP there's a webserver builtin right into PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php